# How to clone any object, including special types?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, clone

I need to write a function that returns a clone of an object.

Something like:

```
// non recursive clone
function clone( obj ) {
  const newObj = Object.create( Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) );
  return Object.assign( newObj, obj );
}
```

This of course only works with objects, not with primitive types: it doesn't work with `undefined`, `null`, booleans, numbers, strings, symbols.

...But it also doesn't work with other types, e.g. `Array`, `Set`, `Map`.

I'd like to support as many types as I can, and my best idea on how to do this is handling *special* types case by case.

I believe that objects with [Internal Methods or Internal Slots](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots) might be the ones that create problems. I'm not fully sure of this and I could not find a list of standard types with Internal Methods or Slots.

Which standard types cannot correctly be created by `Object.create()` exactly?

Comment: In my mind, why would `Object.create` create anything other than an object?

Comment: @evolutionxbox: `Array`, `Set`, `Map` etc are objects. There are only seven [data types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures) in JavaScript; that document explicitly states: "Arrays are regular objects for which there is a particular relationship between integer-key-ed properties and the 'length' property.". And finally `typeof [] === "object"`.

Comment: Whilst that's true, there are special properties to each object types. Array has a `length`, but this isn't set when `assign` is used. You may have to create a custom "assign" for each "type".

Comment: If I recall correctly, the objects in JS have an internal property called [[Class]], and for Array object, its value is "Array". In that sense, JS should differentiate Array Set and Map objects from normal objects internally. You probably need to check something like Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) === Array.prototype.

Comment: @VincentZHANG: I want to do something like that. I need to know which standard types require a special treatment like that though. I suspect that there are many others besides the three I mentioned (for sure `Function`, `Date`, all the typed arrays and, I guess, many others).

Comment: @VincentZHANG do you have any documentation for that?

Comment: So, the question now is what are the possible values for [[Class]] property in ES6? You may look up '6.1.7.4 Well-Known Intrinsic Objects' in this document: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/

Comment: @VincentZHANG: no, the question is still which standard don't work correctly with `Object.create`. I do not believe that you're right about `[[Class]]`, since the only place in the standard that mentions it says "Historically, this function was occasionally used to access the String value of the `[[Class]]` internal slot that was used in previous editions of this specification as a nominal type tag for various built-in objects.": it appears to be an obsolete and no longer used Internal Slot. I couldn't find any relation between it and `Object.create` in the standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which standard types cannot correctly be created by `Object.create()` exactly?

All of them, indeed. Those special types you talk about can only be created using `new` or `Reflect.construct`, supplying the builtin constructor that will create the internal slots.

> I could not find a list of standard types with Internal Methods or Slots.

It's right there in the spec, [chapter 9 *Exotic Objects*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-and-exotic-objects-behaviours) (for internal methods). You can treat ordingary objects just fine (`Object.create` creates one), but you'll have problems with Function objects, Bound Function objects, Array objects, String objects, Arguments objects, TypedArray objects, Module namespace objects, and Proxies. Also, you can find objects with special internal slots by searching for usages of *OrdinaryCreateFromConstructor* (`Generator`, `Boolean`, `Error` and all the other native errors, `Number`, `Date`, `RegExp`, `Map`, `Set`, `WeakMap`, `WeaskSet`, `ArrayBuffer`, `DataView`, `Promise`) and  *ObjectCreate* (`ListIterator`, `Arguments`, all typed arrays, `StringIterator`, `ArrayIterator`, `MapIterator`, `SetIterator`).

> I'd like to support as many types as I can

You should decide (and document) which are supported and which not. Especially for a recursive clone it would be a hassle. Also make sure to document how you deal with non-enumerable or symbol-keyed own properties and getters/setters, the default `Object.assign` behaviour might not be the desired one.

> how to do this is handling special types case by case?

I'd define a `Symbol.for("clone")` method on the prototypes of all the supported types, that way it is easy to extend. Possibly use a known value instead where cloning cannot be supported and/or the default copy algorithm does not make sense, e.g. on iterators or function objects, so that those can be handled with an error message or be ignored.

Comment: I looked at all the types that mention `OrdinaryCreateFromConstructor` and I could find `Boolean`, `Error`, `NativeError`, `Number`, `Date`, `RegExp`, `Map`, `Set`, `WeakMap`, `WeakSet`, `ArrayBuffer`, `DataView`, `Promise`. Would you be able to verify whether these types plus the Exotic Objects you mentioned is a complete list of the standard object types that don't work correctly with `Object.create` ?

Comment: Yes, those are what I found as well.